# Enable switch (transistor) at certain voltage with comparator

Tags: transistors, switches, comparator

So right now I have a boost converter with a capacitor at the output as energy storage. My idea was to use a comparator (DC) comparing capacitor Voltage vs. reference, and the output was connected to the transistor (switch), so the load would be charged with the energy, but it doesn't seem to work as intended. Any suggestions?

Forgot to add: imgur.com/a/FbHe7 I want R2 to enable a switch so there is a connection to R1, when a certain voltage on the capacitor is reached

Comment: I suggest you add a schematic so we have a clue....

Comment: So this: http://imgur.com/a/FbHe7
I want R2 to enable a switch so there is a connection to R1, when a certain voltage on the capacitor is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Put a P-channel MOSFET with its source connected to boost capacitor and drain to load. Gate drive should be inverted - low=active, high=inactive. This can be done by OpAmp's inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQTpMB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Values were not calculated!*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it. What about using a 555 timer, would that be working?

Comment: @dnopas - I don't understand - what will 555 do?

Comment: Setting it up as a monostable multivibrator, then it would discharge when the external capacitor reached 2/3 of the supply voltage.

Comment: @dnopas Well... it's kind of funky.. but why not :) You could tie pins 2&6 to boost cap and ouput pin 3 to drive PMOS gate (or even use pin 7 - discharge). Remember that 555 needs a 10nF cap on pin5.

Comment: The reasonable question is why do you need boost if you already have a higher voltage to supply 555, but it goes really out of scope of the initial question.

Comment: I'm not sure either, if I can use an actual supply or not, but the boost is there because of a solar panel. The goal ind the end is to output DC pulses, not sure if I'm supposed to supply op amps and such with the energy storage.